# $H(G') \otimes_{H(G)} V$ and $f^{-1} \mathcal G \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal O_Y} \mathcal O_X$, the connection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, representation-theory, automorphic-forms, hecke-algebras

1 .  Let $f: (X,\mathcal O_X) \rightarrow (Y,\mathcal O_Y)$ be a morphism of ringed spaces, and let $\mathcal G$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal O_Y$-modules.  Define the inverse image $f^{\ast} \mathcal G$ to be the sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules

$$f^{-1} \mathcal G \otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal O_Y} \mathcal O_X$$

where $f^{-1}\mathcal G$ is the inverse image sheaf.

2 .  Let $\phi: G \rightarrow G'$ be a continuous homomorphism of topological groups of td type, and let $H(G)$ be the Hecke algebra of $G$ (the space of locally constant compactly supported functions $G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with convolution as multiplication).  Define a right $H(G)$-module structure on $H(G')$ by setting

$$(f' \ast f)(g') = \int\limits_{G} f'(g'\phi(g))f(g) \delta_{G'}(\phi(g)^{-1}) dg $$

where $\delta_{G'}$ is the left modular character of $G'$.  Then to any nongenerate $H(G)$-module $V$ (that is, any smooth representation of $G$), define $f_{\ast}(V)$ to be the $H(G')$-module

$$H(G') \otimes_{H(G)} V$$

The reference for this is *Representations of $\mathfrak p$-adic groups* by Pierre Cartier, Corvallis proceedings.

There is clearly something in common between the functors defined in (1) and (2), but I do not know what it could possibly be.  Is there a nice categorical way of thinking about these two notions?

Comment: Although I don't know much about the general situation, it seems like there's an important difference. The functor $f^*$ pulls modules back while the functor $V \mapsto H(G') \otimes V$ pushes modules forward

Comment: Yes.  What I had hoped for was some explanation with $^{\textrm{op}}$ written everywhere.

Comment: Why would opposite categories play a role? Both functors are covariant

Comment: Well $\textrm{op}$ applied to the category of natural transformations from sheaves of $\mathcal O_Y$-modules to sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules.  I don't exactly know what I'm looking for